# Eloquent: Count of an existing record

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I was just wondering if there's a way in laravel to return a count on how many times a record exists with eloquent?

I have two tables: 
cars and brands.

Cars has de fields: `id`, `brand_id`. Brands has de fields: `id`, `name`. Relationship lies on `cars.brand_id = brands.id`.

I have red the documents and couldn't find a solution.

Is there a way that I can how many times a brand is used by a car, so that i get the count like this:

```
Suzuki: 2<br>
Opel: 4 <br>
BMW: 1<br>
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a query:

```
SELECT count(brands.name), brands.name
FROM cars
JOIN brands ON cats.brand_id = brands.id
```

Use the equivalent for Eloquent

```
DB::table('cars')
->select(DB::raw('COUNT(brands.name), brands.name')
->join('brands', 'brands.id', '=', 'cars.id')
->groupBy('brands.name')
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a [BelongsToMany](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships) relationship and then do a count in the query.

```
class Brand {

public function cars() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Car', 'brand_id', 'id');
}
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
Brand::where('name', 'Suzuki')->cars->count();
```

The nicest way to do this inside of your Brand model is with Aggregates:

[Retrieving Aggregates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-aggregates)

Comment: I've made the function, but i get the message that [cars] does not exists?

Comment: If you declared the function inside your model (`public function cars()`) This sould work. It's important that the model's namespace is correct of course, please check first.

Answer (score 0):

If you have proper models you can do this:

```
$brands = Brands::with(cars)->get();

    foreach ( $brands as $brand){
        $yourarray[$brand->name]= count($brand->cars);
    }

dd($yourarray);
```

This will give you a nice array with your brand and number of cars